# Django: How to set ForeignKey using Form data

Tags: python, django

I seem to be missing something. I'm trying to allow the user to choose a genre for their writing, which is then set as a foreign key to the Genre table/model from the Work (writing) table/model.

Error: `Django AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'`
This is how I'm doing it now.

Form.py

```
class post_ow(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(post_ow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['one_shot'].label = "Single Chapter or Multiple Chapters"
        c = []
        genre = Genre.objects.filter(poem = False).order_by('name')
        for b in genre:
            c.append((b.id,b.name))
        self.fields['genre'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = c)

    title = forms.CharField(error_messages = {'required' : 'Title Required'}, widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'style':'width=600px'}))
    summery = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(), error_messages= {'required' : 'Summery Required'})
    genre = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ())
    one_shot = forms.ChoiceField(choices = (
        ('one', 'Single Chapter'),
        ('multi', 'Multiple Chapters'),
        ))
```

Model.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    poem = models.BooleanField()
    ordernumber = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    summery = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_published = models.DateField()
    date_updated = models.DateField()
    one_shot = models.BooleanField()
    completed = models.BooleanField()
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    TYPES = (
        ('FF', 'Fan Fiction'),
        ('OF', 'Original Work'),
        ('PW', 'Poetry Work'),
        )
    types = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES)
    fandom = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank = True, null= True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title + '-' + self.user.email
```

Lines causing error in view.py:

```
g = get_object_or_404('Genre', id = form.cleaned_data['genre'])
pw = Work(title = form.cleaned_data['title'], summery = form.cleaned_data['summery'], user = request.user, one_shot = True, types = 'pw',
        date_published = current_date, date_updated = current_date, completed = True, genre = g)
```

Comment: two questions: what kind of error are you seeing? Please, share it with us. Why are you using a simple `Form` and avoiding to use a `ModelForm`?

Comment: @marianobianchi I'm using a simple `Form` because there are some requirements (some of which I have already added) that this form will need to be able to deal with that `ModelForm` can't do. I'll post the exact error now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form "genre" field as [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) says:

```
genre = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Genre.objects.filter(poem = False).order_by('name'))
```

and remove that **init** method. With this line, you replace the initial values for that field and to put that label to "one_shot" field, you can pass it as a field argument:

```
one_shot = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices = (
        ('one', 'Single Chapter'),
        ('multi', 'Multiple Chapters'),
    ),
    label = "Single Chapter or Multiple Chapters"
)
```